# Spring Boot OncePerRequestFilter shouldNotFilter Junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to add junit test case for my Spring Boot OncePerRequestFilter shouldNotFilter method logic. The logic works fine with real-time REST calls but junit case is failing. Any idea?.

Here is test code.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SpringFilterTest {
    @Test
    public void getHealthTest() throws Exception {
        standaloneSetup(new PersonController()).addFilter(new SkipFilter()).build().perform(get("/health")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
    @Test
    public void getPersonTest() throws Exception {
        standaloneSetup(new PersonController()).addFilter(new SkipFilter()).build().perform(get("/person")).andExpect(status().isAccepted());
    }
    private class SkipFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        private Set<String> skipUrls = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("/health"));
        private AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED.value());
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return skipUrls.stream().anyMatch(p -> pathMatcher.match(p, request.getServletPath()));
        }
    }
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    private static class PersonController {

        @GetMapping("person")
        public void getPerson() {
        }

        @GetMapping("health")
        public void getHealth() {
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting both of junit @Test cases to be successful but health one is always failing(its using Filter).

Incase, if you want to replicate below is complete repo code.
https://github.com/imran9m/spring-filter-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below Expression evaluates to false with `request.getServletPath()` when `/health`

```
skipUrls.stream().anyMatch(p -> pathMatcher.match(p, request.getServletPath()));
```

Change to `request.getRequestURI()` to get the uri and below condition matches the path

```
 skipUrls.stream().anyMatch(p -> pathMatcher.match(p, request.getRequestURI()));
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked after that. Odd that getServletPath doesn't work with junit only. I might be missing some initialization for making getServletPath true.

Comment: If I have a customFilterClass like SkipFilter in your case, but extends from `BasicAuthenticationFilter` which is extended from `OncerPerRequestFilter`. How could we test the override shouldNotFilter method in child???